# send via $.post data + serialized form

Tags: jquery

I would like to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
<form id='f1'>
<input type='text' name='t1'/>
<input type='text' name='t2'/>
<input type='text' name='t3'/>
</form>
```

---

```
var ids=[9,32,45];
$.post(
"test.php", 
{$("#testform").serialize(), page: 7, ids: ids}, 
function(){ alert('success!'); }
);
```

at the server side I want to get the fields from the form + page and ids

is it possible ?

Comment: you should check out ajaxForm http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ at the very least you can see how they serialize the form values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the array of values with [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) (where as [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) creates a string) then add to it before using as the `data` argument to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), like this:

```
var data = $("#testform").serializeArray();
data.push({ name: "abc", value: "1" });
data.push({ name: "ef", value: "3" });
$.post("test.php", data, function(){ alert('success!'); });
```

Then you pass in the array, just like passing in an object, and then [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) gets called internally, turning it into the data string for POST query.

Comment: sorry I've added one more parameter (array), don't know if it matters

Comment: @Omu - nope, doesn't matter, just push it onto the array as well, as many as you want.  Note that you can control how that array is serialized with `$.param(data, true)` instead of `data` or before the call: `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true` (defaults false).

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work, I've edited again my question so that it will be exactly the thing that I'm doing

Comment: @Omu - make sure your elements have *names* not just *ids*, only elements with a `name` get serialized, e.g. : `<input type='text' id='t1' name='t1'/>`

Comment: I was having this problem as well and then I came across this and it doesnt work for me either.  All I get for the serializedArray is [object Object].  The variables never react my php